# How do you set the current GPS navigator location as a variable for destinationA to find distance and time

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am using two scripts here. 
What the script does is finds your current location and updates the map with a marker as well as displays the current address as text.

The second part of the script takes the address that you type in and calculates the distance and time from the second variable, DestinationA.

Currently DestinationA is set to "New York, NY, USA" but
I want to be able to set the DestinationA variable as the latLng position that is found from the GPS navigator.
How do I go about achieving this?

This is my script:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var trackerId = 0;
var geocoder;
var theUser = {};
var map = {};

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var gps = navigator.geolocation;
        gps.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            var opts = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: latLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($("map_canvas"), opts);
            theUser = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: "You!"
            });
            showLocation(pos);
        });
        var trackerId = gps.watchPosition(function (pos) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(latLng);
            theUser.setPosition(latLng);
            showLocation(pos);
        });
    }
}

function showLocation(pos) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latLng
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {
                    $("location").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
                    var addressinput = results[0].formatted_address;
                    document.getElementById('addressinput').value = addressinput;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

//Calc Distance/Time - to fix..
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];

var destinationA = "New York, NY, USA"; //How do I make this my current position?
var destinationIcon = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000";
var originIcon = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000";

function calculateDistances() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var gps = navigator.geolocation;
        gps.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            var opts = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: latLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($("map_canvas"), opts);
            theUser = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: "You!"
            });
            showLocation(pos);
        });
        var trackerId = gps.watchPosition(function (pos) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(latLng);
            theUser.setPosition(latLng);
            showLocation(pos);
        });
    }

    var origin1 = document.getElementById('originDestination').value;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin1],
        destinations: [destinationA],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
        var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

        deleteOverlays();

        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
            addMarker(origins[i], false);
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                addMarker(destinations[j], true);

                document.getElementById('duration').value = results[j].duration.text;
                document.getElementById('distance').value = results[j].distance.text;
            }
        }
    }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
    var icon;
    if (isDestination) {
        icon = destinationIcon;
    } else {
        icon = originIcon;
    }
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': location
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                icon: icon
            });
            markersArray.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
    if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markersArray.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

In the callback of gps.getCurrentPosition() and gps.watchPosition() (depending what you want to do), set destinationA:
    destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);

But I don't really get what you're trying to do... If the destination is now the user position, what's the starting point ?